# Delegate Pass Back not working

Tags: swift, delegates

Have the following in my main "viewcontroller A" as a segue. It is a PageViewController.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "postChoice") {
        let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let controller = dvc.popoverPresentationController
        if (controller != nil) {
            controller!.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Also in my "Viewcontoller A" i have the PostChoiceDelegate reference at the top

My segue is linked to a UINavigationController which pops to a TableViewController.  "View controller B"

VCB

```
protocol PostChoiceDelegate: class {
    func postChoiceSelected(whatStyle: String)
}

//in the vc class
weak var delegate: PostChoiceDelegate? = nil
```

i then have a programmatically made navigation item with target action "uploadPost" and in VCB i have this function which returns a nil delegate.  shouldn't it return "hello" so i pass that to VCA to update a function in VCA of postChoiceSelected() that updates a label.text to Hello?

```
func uploadPost() {
    delegate?.postChoiceSelected("hello")
    print(delegate?.postChoiceSelected("hello"))
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
}
```

I have tried ! instead of ?, etc, but nothing works?  Any comments?

Comment: do you ever assign any value to **delegate**? maybe it's **nil**?

Comment: i think i am in the function delegate.postchoiceselected("hello") ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after many frustrating try and searches... (thanks to all those that helped) I added the following below my if statement in the prepare for segue.

```
        let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let tableviewController:DestinationTableViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! DestinationTableViewController
        tableviewController.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're setting somewhere but I don't see it in the code you've posted.

The **delegate** field an optional value which may or may not have a value. You're not setting this delegate property to anything, thus it's nil and this line won't get executed:

```
delegate?.postChoiceSelected("hello")
```

because delegate is **nil**

How to solve? just set this property to an object instance that implements **PostChoiceDelegate**

So make sure the following line actually gets executed:

```
controller!.delegate = self
```

where **delegate** represents a weak reference to a PostChoiceDelegate and not anything else and **self** actually implements **PostChoiceDelegate**

**UPDATE**: So I would make the following change:

```
let controller = dvc.popoverPresentationController as! ViewControllerThatImplementsYourDelegate
```

because otherwise, that delegate is a **UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate** and not a **PostChoiceDelegate**

Comment: is there a way to have both?  as changing the above results in the popover no longer being a iPad style popover but model instead.  then if i change the segue away for the navigation controller directly to the tableviewcontroller then the post button i implemented isn't there.  Update: one more comments... the error i get when i do as you suggested is Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' to ViewControllerthat has my delegate

Comment: sure, assign the delegate to self once before converting it to your own type of view controller and once after.

Comment: no go... i am new so thanks for being patient.. so i have a segue that goes to a navcontroller, which segues to a tableview.. the viewcontrollerthatimpleents is just the name of the view controller correct?  don't need to make any other identifiers?

Comment: ok, get error when i put as! viewcontrolelrthatimplementsdelegate that "Cast from UIpopoverpresentationcontroller to unrelated type viewcontrolelrthatimplementsdelegate always fails